# Not able to click on an element even by using JavascriptExecutor scrolling

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is my test script. I am not able to click on the element even though I am scrolling the window. I also tried using explicit wait. 
I am getting a WebDriverException saying `Element is not clickable at point (588, 1611)`

```js
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  int success = 0;
  driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin");
  driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("admin");
  driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("admin@123");
  driver.findElement(By.id("tdb1")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Categories/Products']")).click();
  JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,3004)","");
  
  String str = "Mockingjay";
  List <WebElement> lt1 = driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
  Iterator <WebElement> it1 = lt1.iterator();
 
  while(it1.hasNext())
  {
   
   WebElement el = it1.next();
   if(el.getText().contains(str))
   {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(el));
    el.click();
    break;
   }
   
  }
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Edit']")).click();
  
  if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Products Status:']/following-sibling::td/input[1]")).isSelected())
  {
   System.out.println("Changing the product status to 'Out of Stock'");
  }
```

And this is the source code. I tried taking all the `td tags` in a list, iterate among them to find the `element` and clicking on it.

```html
 <tr class="dataTableRow" onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="document.location.href='http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?cPath=&amp;pID=1391'">
                <td class="dataTableContent"><a href="http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?cPath=&amp;pID=1391&amp;action=new_product_preview"><img src="images/icons/preview.gif" border="0" alt="Preview" title=" Preview " /></a> LED TV/52"</td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="center">
<img src="images/icon_status_green.gif" border="0" alt="Active" title=" Active " width="10" height="10" />  <a href="http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?action=setflag&amp;flag=0&amp;pID=1391&amp;cPath="><img src="images/icon_status_red_light.gif" border="0" alt="Set Inactive" title=" Set Inactive " width="10" height="10" /></a></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><a href="http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?cPath=&amp;pID=1391"><img src="images/icon_info.gif" border="0" alt="Info" title=" Info " /></a> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="dataTableRow" onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="document.location.href='http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?cPath=&amp;pID=1494'">
                <td class="dataTableContent"><a href="http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?cPath=&amp;pID=1494&amp;action=new_product_preview"><img src="images/icons/preview.gif" border="0" alt="Preview" title=" Preview " /></a> Mock</td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="center">
<img src="images/icon_status_green.gif" border="0" alt="Active" title=" Active " width="10" height="10" />  <a href="http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?action=setflag&amp;flag=0&amp;pID=1494&amp;cPath="><img src="images/icon_status_red_light.gif" border="0" alt="Set Inactive" title=" Set Inactive " width="10" height="10" /></a></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><a href="http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?cPath=&amp;pID=1494"><img src="images/icon_info.gif" border="0" alt="Info" title=" Info " /></a> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="dataTableRow" onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="document.location.href='http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?cPath=&amp;pID=1507'">
                <td class="dataTableContent"><a href="http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?cPath=&amp;pID=1507&amp;action=new_product_preview"><img src="images/icons/preview.gif" border="0" alt="Preview" title=" Preview " /></a> Mockingjay</td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="center">
<img src="images/icon_status_green.gif" border="0" alt="Active" title=" Active " width="10" height="10" />  <a href="http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?action=setflag&amp;flag=0&amp;pID=1507&amp;cPath="><img src="images/icon_status_red_light.gif" border="0" alt="Set Inactive" title=" Set Inactive " width="10" height="10" /></a></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><a href="http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/categories.php?cPath=&amp;pID=1507"><img src="images/icon_info.gif" border="0" alt="Info" title=" Info " /></a> </td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: Which element is not clickable

Comment: Can you sum up your exact manual steps which you are trying to Automate? Which element is showing `Element is not clickable at point (588, 1611)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I write code like this, I try to make things as simple as possible. I put code that is going to be reused into functions to that they are easier to call and easier to maintain.

In your case, you are looping through all the TDs looking for an element that contains text that matches the product you are looking for. Rather than doing this, we can search for the specific element using an XPath.

```
//td[@class='dataTableContent'][contains(.,'Mockingjay')]
```

You've also got code that scrolls, waits for elements to be clickable, etc. but none of it is necessary. In Java/Selenium, when you attempt to click on an element, if it's not visible the page will scroll automatically.

I've looked at your code and broken it into distinct actions and written a function for each. Then I wrote code that used those functions to do what you are attempting to do. This is working code and I'm not seeing the `Element is not clickable` error.

Here are the functions

```
public static void deleteSelectedCategory()
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#tdb4 > span.ui-button-text")).click();
}

public static void editSelectedCategory()
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#tdb3 > span.ui-button-text")).click();
}

public static boolean isProductInStock(String productName)
{
    return !driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[./td[@class='dataTableContent'][contains(.,'" + productName + "')]]//img[@src='images/icon_status_green.gif']")).isEmpty();
}

public static void login(String username, String password)
{
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.id("tdb1")).click();
}

public static void selectCategory(String categoryName)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Categories/Products']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='dataTableContent'][contains(.,'" + categoryName + "')]")).click();
}
```

Here is the code that drives your scenario

```
String productName = "Mockingjay"; // in stock
// String productName = "Baloon"; // out of stock
driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin");
login("admin", "admin@123");

selectCategory(productName);
boolean inStock = isProductInStock(productName);
System.out.println("Product is in stock: " + inStock);
if (inStock)
{
    editSelectedCategory();
    System.out.println("Changing the product status to 'Out of Stock'");
    // set the product to out of stock
}
```

BTW, you don't have to edit the product to see if it's out of stock. The red light/green light indicate whether it's out of stock. I wrote code that checks to see if a green light is indicated on the page and if it is, then edit the product and added a placeholder where you can add your code to change the product to out of stock, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer you the root cause of 'not clickable'. The problem come from below code:

```
List <WebElement> lt1 = driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

the code will find all td on the page, not only the td inside 'Categories / Products' table.

The first td in the list is already not clickable, and some others also not clickable. This why selenium report not clickable error

To fix your problem, you need to use more strict locator in above driver.findElements(), like this one: `//tbody[tr[@class='dataTableHeadingRow']]//td[@class='dataTableContent'][1]`

But I recommend you take the solution given by Jeffc.

Even above xpath I give can only find td inside 'Categories / Products' table, but there are many unnecessary td in the found list, waste time to iterate each one to filter out them.

Answer (score 0):

I will be very specific in Answering this Question. I will also keep  my approach  simple. The following block of code logs into the url, clicks on **`Categories/Products`**, scrolls down to bring the element **`New Category`** button within [**`Viewport`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) for reference, creates a `List` out of the elements selected through proper **`xpath`** and finally iterates through the list and clicks on the `WebElement` with `text()` as **`Mockingjay`** :

```
package demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Q46143300_gcreddy_site {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin");
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("admin@123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='tdb1']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Categories/Products']")).click();
        WebElement new_catagory = driver.findElement(By.id("tdb1"));
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",new_catagory);
        String str = "Mockingjay";
        List <WebElement> my_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='contentText']//td[@class='dataTableContent']"));
        for (WebElement item:my_list)
        {
            if(item.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains(str))
            {
                item.click();
                break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```